# Sprites with different z values not rendering in correct order

Tags: unity-game-engine

Starting off with some 2D in Unity.  I am running 2019.4.12f1.  I am following the "Let's Make Solitaire in Unity" by Megalomobile.  I am dealing out the cards with the code:

```
IEnumerator SolitairDeal()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            var yoff = 0.0f;
            var zoff = 0.03f;
            foreach (var c in bottoms[i])
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
                GameObject newCard = Instantiate(cardPrefab, new Vector3(bottomPos[i].transform.position.x, bottomPos[i].transform.position.y - yoff, bottomPos[i].transform.position.z - zoff), Quaternion.identity, bottomPos[i].transform);
                newCard.name = c;
                newCard.GetComponent<Selectable>().faceUp = c == bottoms[i][bottoms[i].Count - 1];

                yoff += 0.3f;
                zoff += 0.03f;
            }
        }
    }
```

When it renders in game mode I get this:
[image]

If I switch to Scene mode to inspect the z values, they are correct and everything is properly rendered:[image]

I can increase the zoff value but as I do so, I am getting a good deal of parallax which I do not want.  I have looked for creating a camera that eliminated parallax, but could not find one.  I thought of using tags but managing that would get cumbersome depending on how many cards are in each stack.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the reference from @derHugo below I have found the fix.  First, I changed the camera to Orthographic.  Second I also had to change the camera's depth.  Apparently if the depth is negative, it is still Perspective.

Comment: It looks like the renderer You are using to render cards is using some "Priority" option. What component do You use to render cards? Check it and check material of your cards.

Comment: Maybe this helps [Unity Manual - 2D Sorting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html)